# Unable to install any package due to oem touchpad synaptics problem

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, touchpad, synaptics, oem

Every time I try to install any package from the command line following error appears:

[command line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yITi9.png)

If I try to update system packages I see the same error.
[system update error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZQJV.png)

```
Removing oem-touchpad-synaptics-enable-right-button-1584632 (2) ...
sed: can't read usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package oem-touchpad-synaptics-enable-right-button-1584632 (--remove):
 installed oem-touchpad-synaptics-enable-right-button-1584632 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oem-touchpad-synaptics-enable-right-button-1584632
```

Please Help!

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, we cannot copy/paste from pictures so cannot investigate using detail you provide if in the form of pictures of text.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I can understand the problem and hence I have updated the error from terminal in the question. Hope it helps.